# How to subtract date from MySQL datetime where table is specified as a MySQL function.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm using the following 'DATE(time)' to get date from datetime and works with no errors.

```
SELECT * FROM $t WHERE owner = '$sn' && DATE(time) = '$d';
```

But then when tables are joint I attempt to use "p.DATE(time)" and I get this error.

```
FUNCTION p.DATE does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution'
```

Here's the full code where I use "p.DATE(time)".

```
function get_m_stats($con,$sn,$d=NULL,$t=NULL,$o=NULL){
$get_day = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT m.* , COUNT(p.sid) frequency FROM music m
  JOIN $t p 
  ON p.sid = m.sid 
  WHERE p.sid != '' AND p.owner = '$sn' AND p.DATE(time) = '$d'    
  AND m.perms = 'a'
  GROUP BY m.sid 
  ORDER BY frequency $o 
  LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_day = mysqli_fetch_array($get_day);
echo $row_day['title'];
}
```

How do I write this 'p.DATE(time)'?

Comment: it will be your `date(p.time)`

Comment: Side note: using `DATE` like this will keep the db from using indices.  If you query as a range ([make sure it's lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)), you should be able to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are assigning alias to function. just put it on column name

```
 function get_m_stats($con,$sn,$d=NULL,$t=NULL,$o=NULL){
$get_day = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT m.* , COUNT(p.sid) frequency FROM music m
  JOIN $t p 
  ON p.sid = m.sid 
  WHERE p.sid != '' AND p.owner = '$sn' AND DATE(p.time) = '$d'    
  AND m.perms = 'a'
  GROUP BY m.sid 
  ORDER BY frequency $o 
  LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_day = mysqli_fetch_array($get_day);
echo $row_day['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure `DATE()` is a MySql function - so it cannot exist inside the tabular reference variable `p`.

Hence the correct way to get your data is getting `p.time` and then if you want to convert the dateTime to date, use the MySql function `DATE`.

Hence your query should be :

```
SELECT m.* , COUNT(p.sid)as frequency 
FROM music m JOIN $t p 
  ON p.sid = m.sid 
  WHERE p.sid != '' 
  AND p.owner = '$sn' 
  AND DATE(p.time) = '$d'    
  AND m.perms = 'a'
  GROUP BY m.sid 
  ORDER BY frequency $o 
  LIMIT 1
```